# Why background on section element does not show (height 0)?

Tags: css, html

i noticed that in the following example, note the classes, i am using 960gs in case the classes css interfered

**html**

```
<section id="main" class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_12">
    <article>
    ...
```

**css**

```
header, footer, section, article, nav, aside { display: block; }
#main { background: #fff; }
```

i noticed that `#main` has a `height` of 0 in firebug. also if i do a

```
#main .grid_12 { background: #fff; }
```

it works

i noticed that if i use a `div` instead of `section` the css works

## UPDATE

turns out that its because of the `div.grid_12` or rather `div.grid_x` that causes the problem, if i remove that `<div>` it will work even if i am using `<section>`

```
<section id="main" class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_10"> <!-- <<< this div -->
```

Comment: You need to give it some `height` to display.

Comment: shldn't it take the height of its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer, `grid_x` has `float: left` i need to clear it

Answer (score 3):

From the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-section-element):

> The section element is not a generic container element. **When an element is needed for styling purposes** or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline.

Comment: i know but i am taking the main content area as a part of the app? does that mean that i shld not attach any styles to the section element? or all HTML5 elements? even then, its height shld not be 0?

Comment: @jiewmeng: it seems like it's implemented in a way that doesn't affect the flow of the document, so its height is 0 and you cannot see any styles applied to it. The section element should be used more for its semantic meaning than as a container.  You can either put a container `<div>` inside and apply the styles to that or swap the `<section>` out for a `<div>`.

Comment: it seems even with a `<div>` it does not work ... hmm ... height is 0 wierd

Comment: see update: turns out that its because of the `div.grid_12` or rather `div.grid_x` that causes the problem, if i remove that `<div>` it will work even if i am using `<section>`